# What are A & B pins in this P10 LED module connection?

Tags: led, led-matrix

I purchased an LED module P10 LED module 16x32 matrix which I used to make LED moving display. ([Reference](http://extremeelectronics.co.in/news/p10-led-display-panel-interface-with-avr-atmega8/))

[image]

In that connection, what is A & B?

Answer (score 1):

From the first link on the web-page you linked to

http://digital-wizard.net/avr_projects/p10_led_display_panel_interface

> - EN (Enable) is used for PWM brightness control of the entire panel. That means the MCU can control the brightness by feeding a pulse width modulated signal on this pin.
> - A & B are the multiplex select pins. They take binary input to select any one of the four multiplex rows.
> - Shift clock, Store clock and Data are the normal shift register control pins. The shift register IC used is IC74HC595

Comment: May i get an elaboration in A &B pin selecting ? what will happen that pin selecting . How the scanning done in p10?